# Determine if and which partial postback occurred in pageLoad() with JavaScript in .NET

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, postback

As I understand it, partial page updates with ASP.NET AJAX cause the JavaScript pageLoad() event handler to be invoked.

My question: Is there a generic way of determining in JavaScript from within the pageLoad() function...

i) If the postback was a partial page update or not.

ii) If so, which panel was updated.

My application uses a combination of .NET UpdatePanels & Telerik RadAjaxPanels.  I'm looking for a generic (preferably JavaScript) solution which doesn't require me to specify a unique client-side callback function for each panel, nor set some flag from within each postback event handler to identify itself to the client-side.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To determine if the postback was a partial update or not, you can use `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack`. Here's an example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // get a reference to ScriptManager and check if we have a partial postback
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            // partial (asynchronous) postback occured
            // insert Ajax custom logic here
        }
        else
        {
            // regular full page postback occured
            // custom logic accordingly                
        }
    }
}
```

And to get the Update Panel that caused the PostBack, you can look into `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).UniqueID` and analyze it. Here's an example of doing that:

```
public string GetAsyncPostBackControlID()
{
    string smUniqueId = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).UniqueID;
    string smFieldValue = Request.Form[smUniqueId];

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(smFieldValue) && smFieldValue.Contains("|"))
    {
        return smFieldValue.Split('|')[0];
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

---

**References:**

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1562871.aspx/1
- [Get ASP.NET control which fired a postback within a AJAX UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821569/get-asp-net-control-which-fired-a-postback-within-a-ajax-updatepanel)

Comment: Oh sweet! Two things... I had to change the char '|' in Contains() to string "|", and after the .Split() I took the first half [0] which gives the panel that updated, not [1] which provides the control that caused the update.

Comment: Also, for the benefit of other readers... In order to provide the result to my javascript after the partial update, I had to place some hidden fields in a separate UpdatePanel, and set its attribute: UpdateMode="Always".  This causes the contents of that panel to be updated upon ANY postback - even if it was a partial postback on a separate updatepanel.   Then my javascript can read the values of the hidden fields to determine whether it was a partial postback or not, and get the ID of the panel that was updated.  All good now, thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks Ian for the really good answer.  This was exactly the code that I needed.  Many answers give one or two sentences and then direct the asker to references.  Thanks for concisely spelling out the details! +1

Comment: This does not answer the Question at all. The question is "Is there a generic way of determining **in JavaScript** from **within the pageLoad() function**…" (Highlight mine). But this accepted answer just describes a way **on server side**.

Comment: @DonP You're correct, but this still gives you the ability to do it. If you look at the comments above, Bumpy mentions how to complete what's needed - the server side is a good place to determine what caused the postback, and then it can set hidden values (or something) for the JS to read.