# How do I find out which button clicked inside asp:AsynPostBackTrigger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

> In code-behind, I am able to find out if ddlCategory is clicked which
>   is inside ContentTemplate; however, I also need to find out if
>   buttonAddProduct or bttonSaveProduct is clicked , which are outside of
>   ContentTemplate. Please help. Thanks!

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonAddProduct" Text="Add" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="buttonSaveProduct" Text="Save" runat="server" />

    <!-- Add Client-Side Validation ASP.NET Validators -->
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDetail" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonAddProduct" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonSaveProduct" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCategory" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>

        <ContentTemplate>
            <table class="layoutTable">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" style="vertical-align: top">
                        <label for="ddlProductAttributes" accesskey="c">
                            Attribute Names:
                        </label>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlCategory" AutoPostBack="true" Width="50%" runat="server">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this Post is similar to what you are looking for.

[Determine if and which partial postback occurred in pageLoad() with JavaScript in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893011/determine-if-and-which-partial-postback-occurred-in-pageload-with-javascript-i)

You could also look at the event arguments in the post back as well

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string eventArgument = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    string eventTarget = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! That is what I am doing currently; but, I am only able to get id of ddlCategory. Some reason, by doing above, I am unable to get id of buttonSaveProduct or buttonAddProduct.

It shows empty ("") id for buttonAddProduct and buttonSaveProduct.