# How to get the control that is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, click

How can I get the name of control that was clicked in ASP.NET? (e.g., a LinkBottun)

Comment: possible duplicate of [On postback, how can I check which control cause postback in Page_Init event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
sender.Name;
```

Place this inside the method which is called on the click event.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an OnClick event to it and handle it server-side.