# Simplest way to get Clicked Button in asp.net web form, Page_Load Function

Tags: asp.net

Is there any simpler way to find out which button causes postback?
I have several buttons on my Page, and I need to perform response accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which control caused the postback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269271/which-control-caused-the-postback)

Comment: But this is your own implementation. I think it must be provided by asp.net