# I want to bind data from SQL Server table column at page load in ASP.NET, but it is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to bind data from a SQL Server table column at page load in ASP.NET, but it is not working; code is working in a button click.

This is my code - can anyone help please?

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable subjects = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ToString());
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [name] FROM [supplier]", con);
    adapter.Fill(subjects);

    con.Open();

    DropDownreturn.DataSource = subjects;
    DropDownreturn.DataTextField = "name";
    DropDownreturn.DataValueField = "name";
    DropDownreturn.DataBind();
    DropDownreturn.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "NA"));

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: no i don't receive any errors

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlDataAdapter are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block.

Comment: Please clarify *"it is not working"*: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: i fixed the problem thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

> but it is not working; code is working in a button click.

When user press a button then it create a postback if Postback is enabled on button and you have placed `!IsPostBack` check that may be preventing the code block to bind the dropdown.

**To solve this issue..** At Page_Load, check if your button raised the postback then execute the code to bind the dropdown by following below suggested approach:

[Which control caused the postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269271/which-control-caused-the-postback)

[Way To Know Which Control Has Raised PostBack](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134614/Way-To-Know-Which-Control-Has-Raised-PostBack)

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
  if(postbackcontrol is button1)
  {
     //Bind dropdown 
  }
}
```