# Get reference of image button click event in gridview in http module

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

How do we pass the `Click` event of `ImageButton` inside a `GridView` to httpmodule 
for linkbutton's i am doing this way:

```
if (request.Form.GetValues("__EVENTTARGET") != null)
{

    //If it's a link button execute we can directley check for the params 
    if (request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Contains("xyz"))
    {
        //some Code
    }
```

This is not working for `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to attach an event to a button within a gridview might I suggest in your base page on the prerender event parse through all gridviews on the page (use a recursive findcontrol algorithm) and look for any imagebuttons, if you find one you should then be able to attach an event to it.

EDIT:
I use something similar in the following:

```
 public abstract class AmendmentPopUpWindow : BaseMasterPlanPage
    {
        // override this method if the correct save controls arent being hidden in the popups
        public virtual IEnumerable<WebControl> SaveControls
        {
            get { return Controls.All().OfType<WebControl>().Where(c => c.ID.ToLower().Contains("save")); }
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WebConfiguration.Global_EnableAmendments && SystemVersion.HasValue)
            {
                foreach (var control in Controls.All())
                {
                    if (control is RadioButton || control is TextBox || control is DropDownList || control is RadComboBox || control is CheckBox || control is CheckBoxList ||
                        control is RadEditor || control is RadTextBox || control is RadNumericTextBox)
                    {
                        var webControl = control as WebControl;
                        webControl.Enabled = false;
                        webControl.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var saveControl in SaveControls)
                    saveControl.Visible = false;
            }

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }
```

EDIT: The .All() is an extension method defined as follows (stolen from [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2007/06/29/linq-the-uber-findcontrol.aspx))

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> All(this ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        foreach (Control grandChild in control.Controls.All())
            yield return grandChild;

        yield return control;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this way but it's not coming.is this the way we do .i am doing this in prerequest hand execute                                HttpContext httpContext = (HttpContext)httpApplication.Context;
      
            Page page = (HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page);
            if (page != null)
            {
                foreach (Control childControl in page.Controls)
                {
                    if (childControl is GridView)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: have you tried putting it in your base page code? Also if your gridviews are contained in other elements and hence not directly under the page your code would not find them

Comment: Yup i kept that in the http module page itself.

Comment: try moving it to a physical page and not in the module, you might find that if the code doesn't execute in a prerender or similar type of event that the grid has not been databound and no buttons would appear in it and hence there would be nothing to find

Comment: no not yet.this doesn't work me i guess.i have a http module in a class library and i want everything to happen form there itself.i don't want to touch any part of the .net application.all i do is plug the reference in web.config and it should work

Answer (score 0):

ImageButtons have an additional *quasi-property* in their names which identifies the mouse-coordinates (X and Y).

So to find the ImageButton's name your should iterate through posted parameters and found those which end with `.x` or `.y`:

```
foreach (string item in request.Form)
{
    if (item.EndsWith(".x") || item.EndsWith(".y"))
    {
        var controlName = item.Substring(0, item.Length - 2);
        // some code here
    }
}
```

You could also cound [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3509755/102112) useful. It contains a more generic method to determine which control caused a postback.