# How to know the target control for postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

First Page

```
<html >
<head >
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"            
            Text="Submit to Second Page" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

btnSubmit_Click Event

```
Response.redirect("Page2.aspx");
```

In the Page Load of Page2, how to find which button causes postback?

Comment: You could use a URL-Parameter.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the link provided is for the same page where as mine is for different pages.

Comment: @Dylan You're right, sorry. I misread

Answer (score 1):

on `btnSubmit_Click` event you can pass Query String Paramerter and in Page2 get query string Parameter.

```
Response.redirect("Page2.aspx?btnName=button1");
```

at Load Event of Page2.aspx page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string queryString = Request.QueryString["btnName"].ToString();
      //Here perform your action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Page_Load`, it is not possible to find which button caused the `PostBack`. In the Point-Of-View of Page 2, it is **not** even a Post. It is a completely new request. This is what Response.Redirect does, it indicates to the client browser to do a new Request.

If you really need to know, you can add a URL parameter, and get it as a Query String, as Pankaj Agarwal show is his answer.

EDIT after comment: Besides the Query String, you can use a `Session` like in the onClick:

```
Session["POST-CONTROL"] = "button2"
```

and in the `Page_Load`, you read it as:

```
var postControl = Session["POST-CONTROL"] != null ? Session["POST-CONTROL"].toString() : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the information from which button the post came, you'd implement [Cross-Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's a good article with examples. I'd prefer that method over using a QueryString (which might be slightly faster to implement).

Comment: using Cross-Page Posting how to know which button post-back called.

Comment: I like [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event).

Answer (score 0):

Do have try this solution ?
here : [On postback, how can I check which control cause postback in Page_Init event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event)

```
public static string GetPostBackControlId(this Page page)
{
    if (!page.IsPostBack)
        return string.Empty;

    Control control = null;
    // first we will check the "__EVENTTARGET" because if post back made by the controls
    // which used "_doPostBack" function also available in Request.Form collection.
    string controlName = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlName))
    {
        control = page.FindControl(controlName);
    }
    else
    {
        // if __EVENTTARGET is null, the control is a button type and we need to
        // iterate over the form collection to find it

        // ReSharper disable TooWideLocalVariableScope
        string controlId;
        Control foundControl;
        // ReSharper restore TooWideLocalVariableScope

        foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            // handle ImageButton they having an additional "quasi-property" 
            // in their Id which identifies mouse x and y coordinates
            if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
            {
                controlId = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                foundControl = page.FindControl(controlId);
            }
            else
            {
                foundControl = page.FindControl(ctl);
            }

            if (!(foundControl is Button || foundControl is ImageButton)) continue;

            control = foundControl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return control == null ? String.Empty : control.ID;
}
```