# How to check which control fired in Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

How can we find the control that fired inside of a Master page that also has a panel from code behind?
I have the following layout.

```
Master Page
+---------Panel-----------+
| TextBox  Button1 Button2|
+-------------------------+
|
-------->Child Page
              +-------------------------+
              |        Get From Here!   |
              +-------------------------+
```

When I try the following the  targetId is empty

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    var targetID = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"];

    if (targetID != null && targetID != string.Empty)
    {
    var targetControl = this.Page.FindControl(targetID);
    }
}
```

I want to find out which button caused post back.

### ****Update****

I've tried the following link below without sucess.

[Find on Page Init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event)

Comment: possible duplicate of [On postback, how can I check which control cause postback in Page\_Init event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event)

Comment: Already tried the recommendations those don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `event` that your MasterPage offers to communicate with the Page.

Within your `MasterPage` create something like these

```
public event EventHandler Button1ClickEvent;
public event EventHandler Button2ClickEvent;
```

What is going on here is that you are creating an event that the MasterPage can check for a page that is listening for and fire an event to that page to signal that is has been called. In this case `EventHandler` means that you'll be passing `EventArgs` to the event listener.

You send an event by doing this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Button1ClickEvent != null) // check if a sub page is implementing it
        Button1ClickEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty); // fire the event off
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Button2ClickEvent != null)
        Button2ClickEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Next, wire up your `Page` to implement these events

Add in this to your Page definition

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

Now you can access these events in your page code-behind

```
private void Master_Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is called when the `Button1ClickEvent` is fired from your MasterPage
}

private void Master_Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is called when the `Button2ClickEvent` is fired from your MasterPage
}

protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // Setup an event handler for the buttons
    Master.Button1ClickEvent += new EventHandler(Master_Button1Click);
    Master.Button2ClickEvent += new EventHandler(Master_Button2Click);
}
```

Comment: 'ASP.masterpage_master' does not contain a definition for 'Button1ClickEvent'

Comment: You need to add `public event EventHandler Button1ClickEvent;` to your MasterPage code behind.