# GridView information in DetailsView_ItemCreated

Tags: c#, gridview, detailsview, eventargs

I have a Gridview with a select button. That select button causes a DetailsView to be created. I am using a custom DataBind method for the DetailsView. The custom DataBind method does call detailsview.DataBind() which then fires detailsview_ItemCreated. The EventArgs for detailsview_ItemCreated is empty.

I need to get the ID of the "parent" GridView.

detailsview_ItemCreated fires immediately after detailsview_DataBind() executes in the custom DataBind method so I'm not sure if I could add to EventArgs at some point or if I need to fire the method itself from the DataBind method. Or something else altogether.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: is the detail view inside the gridview column?

Comment: Can you use the selected row property of the parent grid

Comment: @PraveenVenu No, it is a separate control.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 The problem is the program doesn't know who the parent GridView is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a different approach and implemented the Page extension method in [On postback, how can I check which control cause postback in Page_Init event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event) then checked an IF for which GridView caused the postback

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the item created event which will give you the row index of the grid row.

```
int rindex=(((GridViewRow) (((DetailsView)(sender)).Parent.BindingContainer))).RowIndex
```

Comment: This would probably work, but my detailsview is not within my gridview. so .Parent returns the contentplaceholder or page

Comment: As it is not a parent child, when you bind itself, you have to keep it somewhere like session or something and check that when creating row item